# Changing objects in the __init__ method

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to change the objects in the `__init__` method? I want to do it, for example to change all colors of any widgets, by one click:

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self, bg="black"): #<----------
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("400x400")

        self.bg = bg

        self.frame = Frame(self, bg=self.bg)
        self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        self.btn = Button(self, text="Change BG", command=self.chng_bg)
        self.btn.pack()

    def chng_bg(self):
        self.bg = "red"             # I want to change the self.bg for example to use it bye Themes
                                    # without configure each widget seperatly


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App()
    mainloop()
```

So here I'm trying to change the initialized `bg=black` into a red background. I searched for a solution, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Change `App()` into `App(bg="red")`. All of the parameters that you pass in a class like `App` or even `tkinter.Button` are passed into its `__init__` method. That is how python classes work

Comment: That isn't the point. This changes only the Color. But I want to figure out, how I can change the `self.bg` with a function, for different themes. If I want to make 3 themes, one dark, one bright and the other blue each Button have another theme and should override the `self.bg`. I know that I can change it step by step with `configure`, but if I have 100 of widgets it will be hard to change it manually.

Comment: Oh, my bad. You can try using `ttk` which stands for *tk themed widgets*. Or you might want to just put all of the widgets in a list and call iterate over that list calling `.config(bg=<new bg colour>)` on each one.

Comment: I tried `App(bg="red")` direct in the function, it works, but a new window appears. I would need to use `destroy`. But I never seen it in other Apps, if i change the theme, one window is closing and the other is poping up

Answer (score 1):

Changing the variables doesn't change widgets that use the variables. You will need to explicitly change the widgets yourself.

```
def chng_bg(self):
    self.bg = "red"
    self.configure(background=self.bg)
    self.frame.configure(bg=self.bg)
    ...
```

If you use themed (ttk) widgets, you can change the attributes of the theme and all of the widgets that use the theme will automatically update.

Comment: Does changing the variables then using `update()`, update the widgets?

Comment: @CoolCloud `.update()` calls all redraw events which redraws the widgets if they are changed. Or at least that is what I read

Comment: @CoolCloud: changing the variables has no relationship with `update`. The widgets will be refreshed as soon as `mainloop` is allowed to continue. Yes, you can force the screen to refresh by explicitly calling `update`, but that can  have subtle side effects if you aren't careful.

Comment: If I use `update`, I get stacks of windows. If anyone wants to check out, what I exactly mean (this isn't ready yet) : https://gist.github.com/invander80/acc3dce3f10e5366bcd3e9af57590bf0

Comment: @JoeMo: calling `update` will not create any new windows. It will, however, cause any windows that have already been created to be displayed.

Comment: @JoeMo: that code is doing some _very_ questionable things. Every time you do something like `MyApp(fg="#c3d2ff", bg="#1a1c22", box="#252830", flog="#272c35")` you are creating a _new_ window.

Comment: Ok. Next time I will use `ttk`, now I go to change all with `configure`. But thanks for the answers.